# Installation and configuration Asus Xtion Pro (0600) on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros, openni, xtion, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm a student and i am trying to  use an Asus Xtion through ROS ,on an Ubuntu14.04 laptop .
My version of ROS is Indigo. I would be very gratefull if someone could explain me the method of installation.
Precisely i'm interested to catch data from openNI and visualize to RViz.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211888/installation-and-configuration-asus-xtion-pro-(0600)-on-ubuntu-14.04/) by [Saracerno](https://answers.ros.org/users/22880/saracerno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2015-06-24**:
Hi @Saracerno! Try to check [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/195459/skeletal-tracker-for-asus-xtion-pro-live/#209413) post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should start by installing `openni_launch` using `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni-launch` and then following the instructions for [Quick Start](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch#openni_launch.2BAC8-hydro.Quick_start) on that package's main page. If you are lucky this will work fine. If you are running into errors, I'd then try using [openni2_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/openni2_launch). If you are still running into errors, then start searching the internet for your specific errors. There are many people on this site who have asked about a variety of different errors, and many of the questions have several debugging steps that you can try. If you get nowhere with this, then come back here and post what you've tried, and what errors you are getting. Unfortunately the functionality of these devices can be somewhat finicky, and many systems behave differently even with the same drivers and devices. That being said, I am usually able to find some combination of driver version and specific port where I can get everything working.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had some troubles with ROS indigo, and then I tried installing ros-indigo-rgbd-launch ros-indigo-openni2-camera ros-indigo-openni2-launch, and also I modified the files sudo nano /usr/etc/primesense/GlobalDefaults.ini uncommented ";UsbInterface=2" . So The only problem that I have now is this warning "Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...", If you want to try it.

---

Originally posted by [soichirutk](https://answers.ros.org/users/22075/soichirutk/) with karma: 23 on 2016-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1